# Swift. How to get value of variable outside the function

Tags: swift, function, variables

I am working on robotics project and trying to get position of tracking object as a value of the yTrack variable (see the code). I can print yTrack from the func handleVisionRequestUpdate, but I need access to yTrack outside this function in order to use it with other function. getCoord () as an example. Please help!

```
import AVFoundation
import Vision
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

var protocolString: String?
var inputStream: InputStream?
var outputStream: OutputStream?
var dataAsString: String?
var yTrack: Double?

@IBOutlet private weak var cameraView: UIView?
@IBOutlet private weak var highlightView: UIView? {
    didSet {
        self.highlightView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        self.highlightView?.layer.borderWidth = 4
        self.highlightView?.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
}

private let visionSequenceHandler = VNSequenceRequestHandler()
private lazy var cameraLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)
private lazy var captureSession: AVCaptureSession = {
    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
    guard
        let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back),
        let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
    else { return session }
    session.addInput(input)
    return session
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.highlightView?.frame = .zero
    self.cameraView?.layer.addSublayer(self.cameraLayer)
    let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "MyQueue"))
    self.captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
    self.captureSession.startRunning()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.cameraLayer.frame = self.cameraView?.bounds ?? .zero
}

public var lastObservation: VNDetectedObjectObservation?

func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    guard
        let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer),
        let lastObservation = self.lastObservation
    else { return }

    let request = VNTrackObjectRequest(detectedObjectObservation: lastObservation, completionHandler: self.handleVisionRequestUpdate)
    request.trackingLevel = .fast
    do {
        try self.visionSequenceHandler.perform([request], on: pixelBuffer)

    } catch {
        print("Throws: \(error)")
    }
}

public func handleVisionRequestUpdate(_ request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
    test {(yTrack) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let newObservation = request.results?.first as? VNDetectedObjectObservation else { return }
        self.lastObservation = newObservation
        guard newObservation.confidence >= 0.3 else {
            self.highlightView?.frame = .zero
            return
        }

        self.transformedRect = newObservation.boundingBox
        self.transformedRect!.origin.y = 1 - self.transformedRect!.origin.y
        let convertedRect = self.cameraLayer.layerRectConverted(fromMetadataOutputRect: self.transformedRect!)
        self.highlightView?.frame = convertedRect
    }        
    }

   let yTrack = Double(self.transformedRect?.origin.y ?? 0.5)
  //  HERE IT WORKS, yTrack IS PRINTING, BUT I NEED IT OUTSIDE THIS FUNCTION
print(yTrack as Any)
}

public func test (returnCompletion: @escaping (AnyObject) -> () ){
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.yTrack = Double(self.transformedRect?.origin.y ?? 0.5)
        returnCompletion(self.yTrack as AnyObject)
    }       
}

public func getCoord () {
//HERE IT DOESN'T WORK. NOTHING IS PRINTING FROM HERE.
    print(yTrack)
}
```

Comment: let yTrack = Double(self.transformedRect?.origin.y ?? 0.5)
You are declaring new variable here. Make it self.yTractk = ...

Comment: Changed let yTrack = Double(self.transformedRect?.origin.y ?? 0.5) to self.yTrack = Double(self.transformedRect?.origin.y ?? 0.5). Didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `handleVisionRequestUpdate` function.

First of all @Azat was right in comments: when you declare `let yTrack = Double(self.transformedRect?.origin.y ?? 0.5)` you create new variable in scope of this function which has no connection with `var yTrack` from `ViewController`'s scope.

So when you print `yTrack` in this function you print function's internal variable which will be destroyed after function returns. To be able to use `yTrack` outside of a function you need to assign new value to `ViewController`'s `youTrack` and then you'll be able to use it in any function you want

```
yTrack = Double(self.transformedRect?.origin.y ?? 0.5)
```

The second problem is with `DispatchQueue.main.async`. The code inside this block will be performed in most cases after this block

```
let yTrack = Double(self.transformedRect?.origin.y ?? 0.5)
print(yTrack as Any)
```

that's because using this block you tell compiler "create separate «queue» for this block of code and asynchronously perform it when you'll be able to do it" so this line `self.transformedRect = newObservation.boundingBox` will be done in most cases after this line `let yTrack = Double(self.transformedRect?.origin.y ?? 0.5)` and you'll have previous `transformedRect` inside this line which is `nil` if I understand correctly. So remove `DispatchQueue.main.async` from this function or move `self.yTrack = Double(self.transformedRect?.origin.y ?? 0.5)` into it.

Comment: Thank you Peter. I tried to remove DispatchQueue.main.async, move self.yTrack = Double(self.transformedRect?.origin.y ?? 0.5). It doesn't work. Still can get access to yTrack only within handleVisionRequestUpdate function.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the code below. I added a lot of comments but I didn't test it out. But it should fix things. There were a couple confusing things going on. Specifically with the "test" function. Also, you may want to practice using self.myVar or self.myFunc() so that you start to get a better understanding of which variables are local and which are properties on the view controller:

```
public func handleVisionRequestUpdate(_ request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
    // test {(yTrack) in /// remove this since we removed it below
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let newObservation = request.results?.first as? VNDetectedObjectObservation else { return }
        self.lastObservation = newObservation
        guard newObservation.confidence >= 0.3 else {
            self.highlightView?.frame = .zero
            return
        }

        self.transformedRect = newObservation.boundingBox
        self.transformedRect!.origin.y = 1 - self.transformedRect!.origin.y
        let convertedRect = self.cameraLayer.layerRectConverted(fromMetadataOutputRect: self.transformedRect!)
        self.highlightView?.frame = convertedRect

        //
        // Move these into the Dispatch closure
        // let yTrack = Double(self.transformedRect?.origin.y ?? 0.5) // delete this one
        yTrack = Double(self.transformedRect?.origin.y ?? 0.5) // replace it with this one
        print(yTrack as Any)
    }
}

//
// Remove this. I'm not sure what it does, but its making things more complex
//
// public func test (returnCompletion: @escaping (AnyObject) -> () ){
//     DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
//         self.yTrack = Double(self.transformedRect?.origin.y ?? 0.5)
//         returnCompletion(self.yTrack as AnyObject)
//     }
// }
```

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey. After you comments the code became much clearer. I also had to change yTrack to self.yTrack because of the error "Reference to property 'yTrack' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit". But I still have the same question. How can I pass yTrack value as a parameter to other function? Currently self.yTrack is sitting within the closure and global variable yTrack: Double? which is a property of the ViewController is always nil. How can I pass the value to it from the Dispatch closure?

Comment: Oh yeah. Thats weird that I made that typo. Yeah self.yTrack is needed. So because yTrack is a property on the view controller you don't need to pass it as a closure parameter or function argument. You can just use it anywhere in that view controller.

Comment: The problem is that when I try to use yTrack outside the handleVisionRequestUpdate I always get nil even if I do it in the same view controller.

Comment: I guess i would need more information about the order things are happening in. yTrack will be Nil until handleVision function is executed at least once. So it depends on where and when you try to access yTrack that will determine if the value is set. One easy way to check is to set a breakpoint on the line of code where you declare the yTrack property on the view controller. Then the code will pause whenever it gets read or written to. You can then see if you’re trying to read the value before it’s ever set.

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey! You are right. I checked it and found that I tried to access yTrack before the value is set. But I still have the problem: now when I call yTrack it returns only one current value, it's is not updating. For example, if I call yTrack within handleVisionRequestUpdate it's printing out whole flow of values. But from outside I can get only one.

Comment: sorry we have to keep going back and forth. But if you're using the code above the print statement is printing the value of yTrack stored as a property on the view controller: not a local variable. Therefore it is changing and constantly updating yTrack. You just need to keep checking. Add a `didSet { print(self.yTrack) }` underneath the yTrack property. Then whenever it gets updated it will print itself. You can remove the print statement in the handleVisionRequestUpdate function and you'll see that the value is constantly being updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jeffrey! It works now. Hopefully now I'll be able to find a way to pass the values to the other function.

Comment: @kondor Because yTrack is a property on the view controller, any function in the view controller can access it. It doesn't need to be passed around. So in your other function just use self.yTrack to get access to the value again.

Comment: Yes, but value was not updating. I solved this by adding: let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: true) { timer in print(self.yTrack)}. Now I am getting the updated values

Comment: @kondor exactly. Everything is working correctly, you just need to learn more about the timing of how everything happens. It might help to read more about what is commonly referred to as the "view controller lifecycle." This tutorial from Apple covers making an app. It has a section on the view controller lifecycle as well. It might help you to go through the whole project and then come back to your vision project: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH2-SW1

Comment: Thank you, Jeffrey! This is indeed a very useful tutorial.